# VueUse useInfiniteScroll not loading more items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, infinite-scroll, vueuse

I want to load more artworks if the user scrolls down. Like an infinite scroller. I use **[VueUse](https://vueuse.org/core/useinfinitescroll/)** to achieve that and want to use `.slice()` on my vuex computed store to increment 3 more works each time if I come closer to the bottom of the Dom Element.

The first **3 works load** and everything seams fine, but if I scroll down **nothing more loads**. The `sliceNumber` didn't increment and no errors appear. Seams like the `useInfiniteScroll()` function don't trigger any event.

Did someone see the issue? 
Thanks for any help in advance

**Here my Vue Component**

```html
<template>
<div class="Section Explore">

    <ExploreBanner />

    <div
        ref="workDom"
        class="WorkList flex_c_h flex_wrap gap2">
        <Suspense>

            <WorkThumbnail
                v-for="(work, index) in works"
                :key="work"
                :work="work"
                :index="index" />

            <template #fallback>
                <div>
                    Loading...
                </div>
            </template>

        </Suspense>

    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import {
    ref
} from 'vue'
import WorkThumbnail from '@/components/Explore/WorkThumbnail.vue'
import ExploreBanner from '@/components/Explore/ExploreBanner.vue'
import {
    useInfiniteScroll
} from '@vueuse/core'

export default {
    name: 'Explore',
    setup() {

        const workDom = ref(null)
        const sliceNumber = ref(3)
        console.log(sliceNumber.value)

        useInfiniteScroll(
            workDom,
            () => {
                sliceNumber.value += 3
                console.log(sliceNumber.value)
            }, {
                distance: 10
            }
        )

        return {
            workDom,
            sliceNumber
        }
    },
    components: {
        WorkThumbnail,
        ExploreBanner,

    },
    computed: {
        works() {
            return this.$store.state.works.slice(0, this.sliceNumber)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color_p', '#a25aff');
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color_bg', '57, 35, 66');
    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `useInfiniteScroll` composable with Vue 3 and it seems working as expected.

[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-uucblb?file=src/App.vue) (working only in chrome browser due to cors issue)

```js
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { useInfiniteScroll } from '@vueuse/core'
import ShowImage from '@/components/ShowImage.vue'
import { loadMore } from './urls'

const el = ref(null)

const count = computed(() => thumbnails.value.length)
const thumbnails = ref([])

loadData()

useInfiniteScroll(el, loadData, { distance: 10 })

async function loadData() {
  const moreData = await loadMore(3, count.value)

  thumbnails.value = thumbnails.value.concat(moreData)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="el" class="my-container">
    <ShowImage v-for="url in thumbnails" :url="url"></ShowImage>
  </div>
  count: {{ count }}
</template>

<style scoped>
.my-container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 700px;
}
</style>
```

Note that container is made scrollable with height 700px and initial 3 images overflow vertically so that you can scroll down.

When distance between container bottom and last image's bottom became smaller than given `10`, the composable successfully runs `loadData` callback to get more urls that will be appended, etc.